# How to get source of ITEM_SHARED_CREATE and ITEM_SHARED_UNSHARE events?

Tags: box-api

For most events in the Box API, the source field of the event notifies the  client of which object has changed.

For the two sharing events, ITEM_SHARED_CREATE and ITEM_SHARED_UNSHARE, the  source field of the event is always set to null. AFAIK, there's no ID in the event entry that points back to the object that has been shared or unshared. Without doing a full rescan of the Box filesystem via the API, is there a way to determine which files/folders have been shared/unshared?

Here's an example response, note the null source field:

```
{"type":"event",
 "event_id":"57b34bc08ed2720fb72c2a1aba56cc6b399e8e7d",
 "created_by":
    {"type":"user",
     "id":"xxx",
     "name":"Joe Polastre",
     "login":"joe@xxx"},
 "created_at":"2013-02-14T20:39:22-08:00",
 "recorded_at":"2013-02-14T20:39:23-08:00",
 "event_type":"ITEM_SHARED_CREATE",
 "session_id":"925514914511d78b532462",
 "source":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something we need to fix on our end. Please email into us at API AT box.com if you'd like to be updated on the progress we make.

Comment: Check out support request #250162 (support.box.com) from Feb 14, 2013.